# Jenkins maven job not running on linux ubuntu slave

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have Jenkins Master slave configuration setup. Where Both Master and Slave are on running on Ubuntu. I have schedule one maven job on the slave machine. When I trigger this job I am getting below error

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Remote call on Jenkins-Slave-Test-Automation failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1004)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1192)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1181)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:985)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:689)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion
    at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.maven3orLater(MavenUtil.java:276)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1301)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1124)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3578)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Jenkins-Slave-Test-Automation
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1192)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1181)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:985)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:689)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE
```

if I run the pom.xml file from the terminal of slave machine, it is running without any issue. I am suspecting any permission related issues on jenkins slave machine.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: More Info : I am using maven 3.6.0 with JDK 11